# SELECT puxando dados do Banco de Dados

Tags: php, html, select

Não estou conseguindo fazer um select que puxe os dados do Banco de Dados, gostaria que alguém pudesse me ajudar...

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    </head>
    <body>
    <center>

        <h1>Adicionar ítem e categoria</h1>

        <form action="adicionar_item.php" method="post">
            <p><label for="item">ítem:</label>
            <input type="text" name="item" id="item" autofocus></p>


            <p><label for="categoria">Selecione a categoria:</label> <select name="categoria" id="categoria">
                <option></option>                
            <?php

            $sql="SELECT nome FROM categoria";
            $resultado=$conexao->query($sql);

            while($dados = $resultado->fetch_assoc()){
                echo "<option value=".$dados['nome'].">".$dados['nome']."</option>";
            }

            ?>
            </select></p>

            <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar">
        </form>

    </center>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: o que acontece, dá algum erro, pode explicar melhor?

Comment: O select não mostra as categorias que já estão no banco de dados, o select fica em branco

Comment: seu código me parece correto, só não aparece onde inicializou a variável de conexão `$conexao`

Comment: consegui resolver, o problema era que eu não tinha feito o comando para puxar do banco de dados. Agora estou enfrentando novos problemas com a parte de adicionar o item no banco de dados

Answer (score 1):

Você não fez a conexão no Banco de Dados, se estiver usando PDO, deve criar uma nova conexão:

```
$conexao = new PDO('mysql:host=servidor;dbname=bancodedados', 'usuario', 'senha')
```

Comment: Isso provavelmente está vindo da variável `$conexao`.

Comment: eu tinha feito um arquivo que fazia essa conexão, eu só não tinha incluído nesse arquivo para adicionar, era isso que faltava

Answer (score 0):

agora o problema é o seguinte, para adicionar o item, eu preciso só digitar qual vai ser o item e selecionar a categoria para qual ele vai ser adicionado, agora estou com dificuldade para inserir o item na categoria selecionada, meu código está assim

```
<?php
include("conecta.php");

$item=$_POST['item'];
$categoria=$_POST['categoria'];

$sql="INSERT INTO itens (item, id_cat) VALUES (\"$item\", \"$categoria\")";

$conexao->query($sql);

$linhasAfetadas=$conexao->affected_rows;

if($linhasAfetadas > 0){
    header("location:gerenciar.php");
} else {
    echo "<strong>Houve um erro ao registrar os itens e categoria!</strong>";
    echo "<a href=gerenciar.php>Voltar para a página anterior</a>";
}
```